# App Icon not display in above 7.0 android os. it display round default launcer icon

Tags: android, android-studio

**App Icon not display in above 7.0 android device. it display round default Launcher icon How it solved please give me suggestion thanks in advance**

Comment: please post your manifest over here

Comment: please post your manifest...

Comment: Because you have added `android:roundIcon=""` in your manifest **application** tag and this will display round icon in launcher if your launcher support round icon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Please set round icon in manifest file**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score 3):

Apps can now define circular launcher icons, which are used on devices that support them. When a launcher requests an app icon, the framework returns either `android:icon` or `android:roundIcon`, depending on the device build configuration. Because of this, apps should make sure to define both `android:icon` and `android:roundIcon` resources when responding to launcher intents. You can use [Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html#access) to design `round icons`.

[image]

For further information regarding this click [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.1.html).